# Need to place labels on flot bar chart.

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a bar chart created using flot [jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/7/)

Now i need to place labels properly because if there will be no space between stack bars then the label is getting messed up. I am thinking of placing the labels at the right of the bar chart.How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to mess the current canvas, in flot `octx` is the overlay canvas on the main canvas. You can do all the labelings, tooltips, highlightings on the `octx`. I am sharing you basic calling of the canvas.

```
            octx.save();
            octx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            octx.translate(plotOffset.left, plotOffset.top);

            if(series[0].bars.tooltips)
            {
                Label(octx,text,x,y,angle);//write the function which just does the work for you.

            }

            octx.restore();
```